# php array format conversion

Tags: php, arrays

I have an 2d array:

```
$arr = [
    ['b_id' => 535, 'type_id' => 55,],
    ['b_id' => 533, 'type_id' => 55,],
    ['b_id' => 550, 'type_id' => 55,],
    ['b_id' => 658, 'type_id' => 55,],
    ['b_id' => 550, 'type_id' => 61,],
];
```

I want to convert to this format：

```
[
   55 => 
     [
       535 => '',
       533 => '',
       550 => '',
       658 => ''
     ],
   61 => 
     [
      550 => ''
     ]
]
```

I tried using foreach and array_push but the result was not what I wanted.Thanks folks

Answer (score 4):

A simple foreach is all you need

```
$arr = [
    ['b_id' => 535, 'type_id' => 55,],
    ['b_id' => 533, 'type_id' => 55,],
    ['b_id' => 550, 'type_id' => 55,],
    ['b_id' => 658, 'type_id' => 55,],
    ['b_id' => 550, 'type_id' => 61,],
];

$new = [];
foreach ($arr as $a) {
    $new[$a['type_id']][$a['b_id']] = '';
}
print_r($new);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [55] => Array
        (
            [535] => 
            [533] => 
            [550] => 
            [658] => 
        )

    [61] => Array
        (
            [550] => 
        )

)
```